# Editing default custom object home screen

Tags: custom, object

I would like to add a custom button (URL to Flow) to my default home page for my custom object.
Currently, I have a default "New" button to create a new record (see attached screen shot). I'm wanting to add my Flow custom button to this page. Is there a way to do this?

Cheers,
Sean.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do the original task, adding a new button on the "Home" tab of the object, you'd have to build an entire Visualforce page to accommodate the new button (this is a non-trivial task to add a trivial feature). However, you could add the button to the List View tab in just a few easy steps. First, go to your custom object definition, find Buttons and Links, and create a new List button. Next, in your custom object definition, go to the Search Layouts section, edit the List View layout, and add your button. You'll still have to have two clicks (one to go into the list view, and one more to launch the flow), but you'll save yourself hours of development time, depending on how faithful you'd want your Visualforce override to mimic the original tab.

Comment: Dear sfdcfox, thanks very much for your fast reply. Understood what you mean about building an entire visual force page. Wasn't sure I was missing something. I've already done as you have suggested with the button and the search layouts and that is working just fine. Thanks again.